# Return false/ clear timeout is not walking for scroll animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, timeout

The last div at the bottom of the site locks to the bottom of the page and will not let me scroll back up without refreshing. The clear timeout is not working.

What do I need to change to resolve this issue?

Here is my js:

```
function autoScrollTo(el){
    var sliderPx = document.getElementById('nav').style.top; 
    var sliderPos = sliderPx;
    var targetPos = document.getElementById(el).offsetTop;
    if(sliderPos < targetPos){
        scrollDown(el);
    } else {
        scrollUp(el)
    }
}

var scrollAmount = 0;
var distance = 38;
var speed = 16;
function  scrollDown(el){
    var offsetY = window.pageYOffset;
    var targetY = document.getElementById(el).offsetTop;
    var timeLooper = setTimeout ('scrollDown(\''+el+'\')', speed);
    if(offsetY < targetY){
        scrollAmount = offsetY+distance;
        window.scroll(0, scrollAmount);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timeLooper);   
    }
}

function  scrollUp(el){
    var currentY = window.pageYOffset;
    var targetY = document.getElementById(el).offsetTop;
    var looper = setTimeout ('scrollUp(\''+el+'\')', speed);
    if(currentY > targetY){
        scrollY = currentY-distance;
        window.scroll(0, scrollY);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(looper);   
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="autoScrollTo('services');">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="autoScrollTo('feed');">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearFix"></div>
</div><!--/nav-->
```

Comment: Do you have a link with a full example? Makes it a lot easier to see, what's going on ;)

Comment: I agree.  I've set up a fiddle here but it really needs the scroll to elements added to it: http://jsfiddle.net/RVYc5/

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, you should rethink your solution, work with JQuery (animate), and change the scrolling logic, however I changed some things, and added a flag, which catches your infinite scrolling...just a quick workaround, but seriously, start over, or you will not have a decent cross-browser scrolling solution!

```
function autoScrollTo(el){
    console.log(el);
    var scrollPos = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var targetPos = document.getElementById(el).offsetTop;

    console.log(scrollPos + "," + targetPos);
    if(scrollPos < targetPos){
        scrollDown(el);
    } else {
        scrollUp(el)
    }
}

var scrollAmount = 0;
var distance = 38;
var speed = 16;

var lastPosition;

function  scrollDown(el){
    var offsetY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var targetY = document.getElementById(el).offsetTop;
    var timeLooper = setTimeout ('scrollDown(\''+el+'\')', speed);

    if(offsetY < targetY && lastPosition != offsetY){
        console.log(offsetY + "," + targetY);
        scrollAmount = offsetY+distance;
        window.scroll(0, scrollAmount);

    } else {
        console.log("end down");
        clearTimeout(timeLooper);   
    }
    lastPosition = offsetY;
}

function  scrollUp(el){
    var currentY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var targetY = document.getElementById(el).offsetTop;
    var looper = setTimeout ('scrollUp(\''+el+'\')', speed);
    if(currentY > targetY && lastPosition != currentY){
        scrollY = currentY-distance;
        window.scroll(0, scrollY);
    } else {
        console.log("end up");
        clearTimeout(looper);   
    }
    lastPosition = currentY;
}
```